# Tree branches pointing downwards Sapling Addon

Tags: modeling, sapling-addon

I am trying to make random tree shapes using sapling addon, i found that the default tree generation is generating branches pointing upward directions as shown in pic.

I want these branches to point randomly upwards and downwards side of the tree. Is it possible using sapling addons or if not, Kindly advise me the other way out. because in real world all the branches of the tree are not in the same direction

I tried in branch splitting -> angel rotation , but could not able to succeed. Please help me how can i achieve this..??

Thanks[image]

Comment: *" in real world all the branches of the tree are not in the same direction"* that actually depends on the tree. Probably what you want to get is in the Branch Growth > Down Angle Variation, for the second and third levels. I'd advice disabling Bevel for easier calculations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adjusting the settings in the fifth box of the Branch Growth tab (third row, first column) and the last box.

Comment: thanks, making changes in the Curvature box of Branch Growth solved the problem.. :-)